# Finding speed and bandwidth in Android

Tags: android, performance, bandwidth

I am trying to calculate the speed in Android Application whenever it is changed. I got the speed, but I have two problems:

1- It takes time to consider the first change and calculate the speed.

2- The speed is not accurate, when I drive, the speed that is given by the mobile is not the same as car's speed!

My code is:

This one in onCreate method:
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 20000,
                100, mlocListener);

I used LocationListener interface and I implement this method:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){

        if (firsttime) {
            la1 = loc.getLatitude();
            lo1 = loc.getLongitude();
            firsttime = false;
            start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        } else {
            la2 = loc.getLatitude();
            lo2 = loc.getLongitude();
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long difftime = end - start;
            double diffhoure = (double) difftime / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            double dis = distance(la1, lo1, la2, lo2);
            double speed = dis / diffhoure;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Your speed is" + speed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            la1 = la2;
            lo1 = lo2;
            start = end;
        }

    }
```

the method for finding the distance is:

```
double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    // this method uses Haversine Formula
    double R = 6373; // earth radius in KM.

    double dlon = Math.toRadians(lon2 - lon1);

    double dlat = Math.toRadians(lat2 - lat1);
    double a = (Math.sin(dlat / 2)) * (Math.sin(dlat / 2))
            + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1))
            * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) * (Math.sin(dlon / 2))
            * (Math.sin(dlon / 2));
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

    double d = R * c;
    return d;
}
```

Also, could you please tell me a good way for calculating bandwidth for both WiFi and 3G?

Thank you in  advance.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the wifi bandwidth with this code :

```
    public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {



        WifiManager mgr = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo networks = mgr.getConnectionInfo();
        if (networks != null) {
            Integer linkSpeed = networks.getLinkSpeed();


            Log.i("linkSpeed**************",linkSpeed +"");

        }
}
```